# Highest score in a snooker frame

Tags: snooker

What is the highest score ever achieved in one frame in a ranked event, not break i know it's 147, but for example the other player made some faults and the other player get points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_break#Breaks_exceeding_147), citing [this BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/other_sports/snooker/3750162.stm):

> In October 2004, during qualifying for the UK Championship, Jamie Burnett became the only player to record a break of more than 147 in tournament play, when he scored **148** against Leo Fernandez. He took the brown as the free ball, then potted the brown again followed by the 15 reds with 12 blacks, two pinks and a blue, then the six colours.

The theoretical maximum is 155, but as of the writing of this answer, 148 is the highest ever achieved in a professional match.

Comment: This does not answer the question, they want the highest frame score.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje You're right, I somehow missed that when answering the first time. I'd delete it, but you can't delete accepted answers, unfortunately, and there's little chance of OP unaccepting it as they haven't been active in some time.

Answer (score 3):

A player can score more than 147 by scoring foul points. The 'miss' rule means high foul point totals are not uncommon.
The highest individual frame score is 178-6 (Jimmy Robertson 2021) beating the previous 167-6 (Dale 1999). Yesterday Milkins beat Selby 164-0 (Welsh Open 2023) - this may be the record frame score to nil.
Links: https://www.snooker.org/plr/records.shtml   and.
https://cuetracker.net/head-to-head/nigel-bond/dominic-dale

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the question is about a frame. Even is a break can be more than 147.